# Obtaining XML field value on specific condition on another field - The fastest way

Tags: java, xml

There has been many ways. But I am just curious to know if there is a faster way (considering development time) or an API where I could retrieve a specified field's value on specific criteria on other field.

That is, consider I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <port:getAllIdentificationsResponse xmlns:port="http://www.ibm.com/Party">
         <ResponseControl xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/schema">
            <ResultCode>SUCCESS</ResultCode>
            <ServiceTime>8</ServiceTime>
         </ResponseControl>
         <PartyIdentificationBObj>
            <IdentificationIdPK>1234</IdentificationIdPK>
            <IdentificationValue>DRIVER LICENSE</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationNumber>5678</IdentificationNumber>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>EVERGREEN</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>7777</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>
         </TCRMPartyIdentificationBObj>
         <PartyIdentificationBObj>
            <IdentificationIdPK>2345</IdentificationIdPK>
            <IdentificationValue>SOURCE IDENTIFIER</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationNumber>429043825</IdentificationNumber>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>EVERGREEN</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>8888</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>
         </TCRMPartyIdentificationBObj>
         <PartyIdentificationBObj>
            <IdentificationIdPK>3456</IdentificationIdPK>
            <PartyId>249443337882014002</PartyId>
            <IdentificationType>300</IdentificationType>
            <IdentificationValue>MEMBERSHIP NUMBER</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationNumber>429043825</IdentificationNumber>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>EVERGREEN</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>9999</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>
         </TCRMPartyIdentificationBObj>
         <PartyIdentificationBObj>
            <IdentificationIdPK>4567</IdentificationIdPK>
            <IdentificationValue>SOURCE IDENTIFIER</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationNumber>UTS~^~3229004~^~1</IdentificationNumber>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>EVERGREEN</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateUser>
            <PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>1111</PartyIdentificationLastUpdateTxId>
         </TCRMPartyIdentificationBObj>
      </port:getAllIdentificationsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to return the **IdentificationNumber** of all fields whose **IdentificationValue** is **SOURCE IDENTIFIER**?

My result should be *429043825*, *UTS~^~3229004~^~1*.

An advice on what way could be the best would be more helpful.

Comment: The most straightforward and dumb is to extract it with the Regex. Otherwise use DOM Parser or SAX Parser.

Comment: If you already know how to do this multiple ways, go ahead and [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @Nikolas: Never use regex to parse XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest is meaningless with specifying for whom and by what.  Fastest in terms of dev time or processing?  If for processing, it's almost certainly not going to matter, but you'd have to measure against particular software and hardware environments.

Save yourself (likely) unnecessary worry and just use XPath...

This XPath,

```
//PartyIdentificationBObj[IdentificationValue='SOURCE IDENTIFIER']/IdentificationNumber
```

will return all `IdentificationNumber` element children of `PartyIdentificationBObj` elements with child `IdentificationValue` elements whose string value equals `"SOURCE IDENTIFIER"`, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance Kjhughes !